# Executing JavaScript in Adobe Flex without using Browser Control

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, adobe

I want to add scripting functionality to my Adobe Flex application. I know it's possible to use the Browser control, and add the script packaged as a HTML file to the Browser control, and expose Flex objects. However I'd like to if it is possible to execute JavaScript without using the Browser control.

UPDATE: I guess my question hasn't been clear enough. I'll explain what I'm trying to do.

I want to make my application customizable using JavaScript ie., add scripting/plugins to my application dynamically.
I realize that it's possible to dynamically execute Javascript by inserting the JS code into the HTMLLoader control. I would like to know there is a direct way to execute JavaScript without inserting it into the HTMLLoader control.

Comment: Please make it more clear. Are you talking about a web app or AIR app ?

Comment: It is an AIR desktop application, to which I want to add scripting functionality. I would like to do it without using the HTML control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a web application, then the following should work

```
var retval:int = ExternalInterface.call("myfunction", "arg1","arg2");
```

You can also use URLRequest to accomplish this

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:myfunction()");
navigateToURL(req,'_self');
```

If you are in a AIR application, something like this should work

```
var html:HTMLLoader = new HTMLLoader();
html.load(new URLRequest("...URL..."));
html.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myeventhandler);
```

In the event handler you can do this.

```
html.window.document.location =  "javascript:myfunction(arg1)";
```

Comment: Here, you are essentially using the HTML control. I wanted to know if it was possible to execute a script directly. Something similar to Mozilla's Rhino project - http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want, you can add your Javascript code into your `{nameOfApplication}.html` which exists in `bin-debug` of your project.

**Notice:** with this method, the javascript code will be disappear always when you compile. It's about the HTML wrapper.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I wanted. I've edited the question. Hopefully it's clearer now.